# Chaijs - assert multiple keys and values in object

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I am rewriting some tests and I have a question. Lets say that I have an object with 10 key/value pairs. Some values are strings and some are numbers.

What I do not want to do is check every key/value separately but rather check all strings and numbers together.

So is there a better way to do this:

```
expect(a).to.have.property(“b”).that.is.a(“string”).and.not.empty;
expect(a).to.have.property(“c”).that.is.a(“string”).and.not.empty;
expect(a).to.have.property(“d”).that.is.a(“number”);
expect(a).to.have.property(“e”).that.is.a(“number”);
```

I would like to group the first two and last two in one assertion. Is this doable?

Many thanks!

Comment: I gave you an example pattern in an answer, but note that there is value in knowing exactly which property might cause failure and reporting that granular failure cause in the test report. There's nothing inherently wrong with an assertion for every property.

Comment: Your solution is great. I agree with what you stated but can’t I add the name of the failing property to the message with a template string somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with the [`assert`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_assert) function, like in this example code:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwIYGcUFNYF84DMoQhwDkAxgBZLDEDcAUHaRAHYrxJwC8idccARgC4S5dABsxEYgBpecUsOIB3aGIAmMuWuEBGWX3TCATLKz06AegtwAKqLhgCYTDACecZkhDoUcJeWAKeWgoH0hmNTgYCCj7NihgZgBzOAA3JDEAVx9BRhY2OHiABScUYQAKAGt0VwhcKNdnOrgkAEoAbQBdLjh24n4ZElJiOAsAKjh0GFIAOjgxi07zVAxYcrli0pn0VMxXKpquAD44db4+avdElrk+ADI7hqb6pHbL7s5PknjEpOJbuAPU6vd4tXw-ZKtGZidDJGDkOAnAAMclarX0JAAmhBMlBCjAEskHE4XO5MAQ8d40Egkug4KJQppWuYrLZ7I4IM5YO5PFS-AEgkwoKEUOFItFYnTmJkQPxMGkMtkynlWPBpSASpyyqdLs03M8Wh0Pr1iBppCR0CNxpNpnMFksGCsXGcPDLNWAUNtdlB9pdjnA-dcOED9ehmiCah8vsR1XKoMR0XJiNjca7ZfKOVy3JNhdA4FSUDS6QzLbJmUA)

```ts
import {assert} from 'chai';

const a = {
  b: 'hello',
  c: 'world',
  d: 1,
  e: 2,
};

// The property names which correspond to the string values:
const strProps: (keyof typeof a)[] = ['b', 'c' /* etc. */];

assert(
  strProps.every(key => (
    key in a
    && typeof a[key] === 'string'
    && (a[key] as string).length > 0
  )),
  'Your string property error message here',
);

// The property names which correspond to the number values:
const numProps: (keyof typeof a)[] = ['d', 'e' /* etc. */];

assert(
  numProps.every(key => key in a && typeof a[key] === 'number'),
  'Your number property error message here',
);
```

Comment: This is great but with the drawback that you don’t know which property failed. Can we edit this so we can include that too?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548435/chaijs-assert-multiple-keys-and-values-in-object/74548790?noredirect=1#comment131596729_74548790) @AlanKnap The `every` method doesn’t provide that information: it simply returns a boolean.

Comment: I know, was hoping we can use something else instead. I’ll play around with this and try to find a solution and otherwise I’ll just assert every single property independently.